# How to remove title fields in form design caption in Dynamics AX?

Tags: field, axapta, title, caption

I open form with menuitembutton and in caption are visible title fields from datasource. Can I remove it? This form should be for creating new records and this title fields can be confusing.

In my case title bar is not replaced with text "New record". But I insert in run() method line `Table_ds.create()` and change in menuitem properties EnumTypeParameter, EnumParameter to value "FormOpenMode"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some additional methods. You can change the `caption` a couple of ways.

Override the form's `init` method and this will work, but still leaves the `(TitleField1, TitleField2)` at the end of the caption.

```
public void init()
{
    super();

    element.design().caption("New Caption");
}
```

Alternatively, override the form's `run()` method and do something like this:

```
public void run()
{
    super();

    WinAPI::setWindowText(this.hWnd(), "New Caption without other stuff");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Overriding method run() helps me.

Answer (score 3):

The title fields can be removed from the form title bar by clearing the `TitleDatasource` property of the form's design node.

Note that when a new record is created, the title fields in the form title bar will be replaced with the text "New record".